# How to employ a variable as parameter inside template of the Eigen::Map class

Tags: c++, eigen

I encountered the following issue in Eigen taking a set of elements uniformly spaced within a vector employing the class Map.

```
void func (int A, int B)
{
    Eigen::Map<VectorXf,0,Eigen::InnerStride<B> > myMap(v.data() + B - 1, A);
}
```

The issue is in the 3rd argument of the template "Eigen::InnerStride". The compiler says "error: 'B' is not a constant expression".
I tried to fix as follows:

```
constexpr int varToConst(int arg)
{
    return arg;
}

void func (int A, int B)
{
    Eigen::Map<VectorXf,0,Eigen::InnerStride<varToConst(B)> > myMap(v.data() + B - 1, A);
}
```

but I get the same error. The int B variable is passed by the main and unfortunately, inside the main, it cannot be a const.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't use variables as template parameters. Templates are a compile time concept and don't exist at runtime. "constant expression"actually  means a compile time constant. Probably the developers of Eigen have thought of such cases as well, I suggesst you take a look in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic stride, like this:

```
void func (int A, int B) {
    Eigen::Map<VectorXf,0,Eigen::InnerStride<>> myMap(v.data() + B - 1, A, Eigen::InnerStride<>(B));
}
```

If this section is performance critical, and if the number of feasible B's is small (like - maybe the only valid values are `B=2` and `B=3`), then you can also template `func()` on B's value. Then you would have something like `template <int B> func(int A)`, and `func<2>(/*A=*/10);` at the call site.

Comment: Thank you very much! You got it. Great job :)